# SonataAdminBundle configureShowFields with nested entities

Tags: php, symfony, sonata-admin

For a project which uses symfony2 and the SonataAdminBundle, I am trying to figure out how to embed complete related entities in the show action.

To get more into detail, let's say I have a `Article` and a `Comment`. On the show view for the `Article`, I'd like to show each `Comment` with multiple properties as well as an EDIT on each and a CREATE to add another comment to that `Article`.

I was able to get it to get it to display a list of `Comment` entities which link to the Entity by using `->add('comments')`, but that's not enough. I need to have the entity really embedded!

Is there a way to do this without coding it on our own? And if doing it manually is the only way, what's the best approach? Rewriting the template?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simplest way is to specify a template for the collection:

```
$showMapper->add('comments', 'collection', [
    'template' => 'YourBundle:SomePath:SubPath/show_comment_collection.html.twig',
]);
```

Look to `SonataAdminBundle:CRUD:base_show_field.html.twig` for a template to use as an example. And, in that template, you can loop over the `value` variable. For example:

```
{% block field %}
    <ul>
    {% for comment in value %}
        <li><a href="{{ path('some_route', {'id': comment.id}) }}">
            {{ comment.id }} - {{ comment.otherProperty}}</a>
        </li>
    {% else %}
        <li>No comments</li>
    {% endfor %}
    </ul>
{% endblock %}
```